# Move SQL 2008 database to Azure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql, azure-sql

I need to move a SQL 2008 R2 on-premis database to an Azure SQL cloud database. The database is to big to script out with data and Azure SQL cloud cannot restore a standard .bak file.

Trying to use Tasks --> Export data-tier application from [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2013/09/26/how-to-export-an-on-premises-sql-server-database-to-windows-azure-storage/) guide toghether with SSMS 2016 to create the .bacpac file that I will import to Azure SQL cloud. But I keep getting this errormessage:
User [test_user] has an unresolved reference to login [test_user].

See below for complete message.
[image: Error]

Why do I get this error? 
Maybe there is a better way to export / import a database from SQL 2008 to Azure SQL?

Comment: Check if you have the privileges to view definition's on logins.

Comment: Thank you! Setting myself as a SysAdmin solved the problem.
Should have thought about the permissions myself.. 
Do set your comment as an answer.

Comment: I put it in a small answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is usually caused by a lack of permissions.

As you are creating a bacpac file to transfer a database to azure, we can rule out permissions on the target server.
Which means you are most likely missing permission to read the login definitions on the source server.

You will need to grant your user `VIEW DEFINITION ON LOGIN` permissions, or add him to a role that has those permissions built in.